# Why Membership.CreateUser Failed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

For this [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8t4h2es):

if `CreateUser("username@email.com","pwd")` , failed with error message :The e-mail address provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.

but `CreateUser("username@email.com","pwd","username@email.com")` , succeed!

why?

Comment: Update your web.config membership section settings... You need to change that...

Comment: On the documentation link you have posted, under "Remarks": `...If the RequiresUniqueEmail property is true, you will need to use one of the CreateUser overloads that allows you to specify an e-mail address for the user being created. Otherwise, a MembershipCreateUserException will be thrown`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to think of the methods like this:

```
CreateUser(Username, Password);

CreateUser(Username, Password, Email);
```

Without reflecting the code I couldn't say 100% for sure, but I'll bet those functions just call an internal function that takes in every possible parameter.

So your first call (simplified) is actually:

```
CreateUser("username@email.com", "pwd", null);
```

If you have configured your provider to require email address, then clearly `null` is not valid.

From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8t4h2es):

> The SqlMembershipProvider provides an option to require a unique
>   e-mail address for each user. **If the RequiresUniqueEmail property is
>   true, you will need to use one of the CreateUser overloads that allows
>   you to specify an e-mail address for the user being created.**
>   Otherwise, a MembershipCreateUserException will be thrown.